# how to form and traverse an array of linked list in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have written a single linked list for insertion of elements, where each element is having two data values. Now what I want is that to make like jagged array. That means I want a 1d array and where each element will be a linkedlist of items. Is it really possible to make the below single linkedlist into an array of linkedlist, i.e. L[0],L[1], etc. each will be the starting of similar linkedlist. Then what shall I modify in the code given below so that I can form and traverse and get the values printed.

```
// Java Program to insert in a sorted list
class LinkedList1
{
Node head;  // head of list

/* Linked list Node*/
class Node
{
    int s;
    int a;
    Node next;
    Node(int starting_time,int arrival_time) {s = starting_time; a=arrival_time;next = null; }
}

/* function to insert a new_node in a list. */
void sortedInsert(Node new_node)
{
     Node current;

     /* Special case for head node */
     if (head == null || head.a >= new_node.a)
     {
        new_node.next = head;
        head = new_node;
     }
     else {

        /* Locate the node before point of insertion. */
        current = head;

        while (current.next != null &&
               current.next.a < new_node.a)
              current = current.next;

        new_node.next = current.next;
        current.next = new_node;
     }
 }

              /*Utility functions*/

/* Function to create a node */
Node newNode(int s,int a)
{
   Node x = new Node(s,a);
   return x;
}

 /* Function to print linked list */
 void printList()
 {
     Node temp = head;
     while (temp != null)
     {
        System.out.print("["+temp.s+","+temp.a+"] ");
        temp = temp.next;
     }
 }

 /* Drier function to test above methods */
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
     LinkedList1 llist = new LinkedList1();
     Node new_node;
     new_node = llist.newNode(5,6);
     llist.sortedInsert(new_node);
     new_node = llist.newNode(10,2);
     llist.sortedInsert(new_node);
     new_node = llist.newNode(7,3);
     llist.sortedInsert(new_node);
     new_node = llist.newNode(3,4);
     llist.sortedInsert(new_node);
     new_node = llist.newNode(1,5);
     llist.sortedInsert(new_node);
     new_node = llist.newNode(9,1);
     llist.sortedInsert(new_node);
     System.out.println("Created Linked List");
     llist.printList();
 }
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is create datastructure similar to Hashmap i.e array of linkedlist. Obviously, it is possible. But I didn't what should the linkedlist contain. For eg. You added some elements to the linkedlist then what linkedlist should be at arr[0], arr[1].

Comment: Almost. I want to create example: arr[0]= {(5,6),(10,2),(7,3),(3,4)}, arr[1]= {(11,2),(6,33),(13,4)},etc..

Comment: what do you mean by like??

Comment: yep. arr[0],arr[1], .. each one will be holding a big single linked list . That's all I want

Comment: So what is the problem ? You can create it via LinkedList1[] arr;

Comment: I have tried a lot. every time it says some or the other error. Its becoming really a mess in merging the program to make such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have wrapped up the LinkedList1 class inside LinkedListArray and create couple of constructors and a get and insert method. Similarly, you can write other methods as required. Hope this will make things clear.

```
public class LinkedListArray{

    private int DEFAULT_CAPACITY=10;
    private int SIZE=0;

    private LinkedList1[] arr;

    public LinkedListArray() {

        arr=new LinkedList1[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];

    }   

    public LinkedListArray(int capacity) {

        arr=new LinkedList1[capacity];

    }

    public LinkedList1 insert(int index, LinkedListArray.LinkedList1.Node Node) {

        if(arr[index]==null)    arr[index]=new LinkedList1();

        arr[index].sortedInsert(Node);;
        SIZE++;
        return arr[index];
    }

    public LinkedList1 get(int index) {

        return arr[index];
    }

    public int size() {

        return SIZE;
    }


//Java Program to insert in a sorted list
class LinkedList1
{

public LinkedList1() {} 
Node head;  // head of list

/* Linked list Node*/
class Node
{
 int s;
 int a;
 Node next;
 Node(int starting_time,int arrival_time) {s = starting_time; a=arrival_time;next = null; }
}

/* function to insert a new_node in a list. */
void sortedInsert(Node new_node)
{
  Node current;

  /* Special case for head node */
  if (head == null || head.a >= new_node.a)
  {
     new_node.next = head;
     head = new_node;
  }
  else {

     /* Locate the node before point of insertion. */
     current = head;

     while (current.next != null &&
            current.next.a < new_node.a)
           current = current.next;

     new_node.next = current.next;
     current.next = new_node;
  }
}

           /*Utility functions*/

/* Function to create a node */
Node newNode(int s,int a)
{
Node x = new Node(s,a);
return x;
}

/* Function to print linked list */
void printList()
{
  Node temp = head;
  while (temp != null)
  {
     System.out.print("["+temp.s+","+temp.a+"] ");
     temp = temp.next;
  }
}

/* Drier function to test above methods */

}


public static void main(String args[])
{
    LinkedListArray arr=new LinkedListArray();


  arr.insert(0,  new LinkedListArray().new LinkedList1().newNode(5, 4));
  arr.insert(0,  new LinkedListArray().new LinkedList1().newNode(10, 4));
  arr.insert(0, new LinkedListArray().new LinkedList1().newNode(4, 34));


  System.out.println("Created Linked List and inserted in array");
  arr.get(0).printList();
}
}
```

Comment: I have just tried the program, it is showing this error. LinkedListArray.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    public LinkedList1 insert(int index, Node Node) {
                                         ^
  symbol:   class Node
  location: class LinkedListArray
1 error

Comment: just import LinkedListArray.LinkedList1.Node

Comment: after Adding" import LinkedListArray.LinkedList1.Node "statement at the top.   F:\Java_Programs>javac LinkedListArray.java
LinkedListArray.java:1: error: package LinkedListArray.LinkedList1 does not exist
 import LinkedListArray.LinkedList1.node;
                                   ^
LinkedListArray.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
    public LinkedList1 insert(int index, Node Node) {
                                         ^
  symbol:   class Node
  location: class LinkedListArray
2 errors

Comment: I don't know your package name. You know how to import classes, right?

Comment: Yes,i do know. but can I not the run the program alone

Comment: There is no package with this code. I am running this single program in command prompt. or shall I need to build a package before compiling this type of programs.

Comment: Okay, you don't have any package. I have updated the code to work without package.

Comment: Can you say why you have given private int SIZE? Is it serving some purpose in code@Shubham Kadlag

Comment: I have edited the code to tell you where can you use size. I added size++ to insert method. similarly you can add size-- to delete method. I also wrote a getter method for size. This way you can get size of linked list.

Comment: Its showing:
LinkedListArray.java:36: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to LinkedListA
rray.LinkedList1
        return SIZE;
               ^
1 error

Comment: Updated. Please check